# The isomorphism in "Scott's representation theorem"

Tags: lambda-calculus, category-theory

In the essay [Relating Theories of the lambda-calculus](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/dump/Scott/ScottRelating.pdf), Scott constructs (from page 418) a category that exhibits a chosen lambda calculus $ L $ with $ \beta $-equality as the collection(s) of morphisms $ E(U)_n = U^n \to U $.

Now, the construction is fairly straightforward. Also, we have a bijection of the terms without free variables: $ \varphi_0: E(U)_0 \xrightarrow{\sim} L_0 $, given by $ f \mapsto f(\lambda x_1, x_1) $, with inverse $ g \mapsto \lambda x_1, g $. However, my question is: how does one show a bijection between the terms *with* free variables of $ E(U) $ and $ L $?

I tried sending a term $ f: E(U)_n $ first to $ \lambda x_1 \dots x_n, f : E(U)_0 $, then using $ \varphi_0 $ to send it to $ L_0 $, and finally adding the free variables back in again:
$$ \varphi_0(\lambda x_1 \dots x_n, f) x_1 \dots x_n : L_n $$
However, I was not able to show that this commutes with the $ \lambda $-abstraction or the application. Is there a (better) way to construct the bijections $ E(U)_n \xrightarrow{\sim} L_n $?